# Should I use "the" before "checkout"?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I currently develop an e-commerce website.
I got confused about this sentence:

- use coupon code at checkout
- use coupon code at the checkout

Which should I use? 
Is "the" neccessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "the" is not necessary; in fact it sounds funny. I can't exactly explain why. (Maybe it has something to do with the fact that on a website, checkout is more like a time than a place?) But "at the checkout" (speaking of a website) is not idiomatic in AmE.

---

By the way, I caution you not to fall into the trap of treating "checkout" as a verb. It is a noun (*at checkout*) or an adjective (*checkout procedure*) but NOT a verb (*when you checkout*).

So be consistent in labeling buttons, either as nouns or as verbs, thus:

- If there's a  **LOG OUT** button,  "checkout" button should say **CHECK OUT**.  (both are verbs)
- If you have a **LOGOUT** button, meaning "press here to *do a logout*", the  "checkout" button should say **CHECKOUT**, meaning "press here to *go to checkout*". (both are nouns)

Comment: When you are speaking of a physical checkout e.g. at a supermarket, in Britain the definite article would always be used. *There was a queue of three people at the checkout*.

Comment: Good point. Likewise in America. But the common practice for referring to checkout _on a website_ seems to be _at checkout_. Edited my answer to clarify this only applies to website.

Comment: I think this is because at a supermarket, the checkout is a particular place; in cyberspace, it's a process of mouse clicks, filling in text boxes, and selecting from drop-down lists.

Comment: I got it. Use "the" when checkout is a place (in the market,..), not use when checkout is a step (in a process)